# How to add an image link inside "configure::write()" in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to set a logo for my application.

In my `AppController.php` page I wrote the following line of code:

```
Configure::write('CompanyLogo','echo $this->Html->image('logo.png', $options = array());');"
```

But, It's not working for me. Do you have any suggestion how to make it work? Thanks

Comment: Did you get any error? help us to help you

Answer (score 1):

Components in controllers and helpers in views. You are currently trying to use a helper in a controller, which won't work.
instead write the image_name in config :

```
`Configure::write('Config.logo', 'logo.png');`
```

use this into layouts/views

```
$image_name= Configure::read('logo');

$this->Html->image($image_name, array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "echo" inside a function parameter. So it should be 
Configure::write('CompanyLogo',$this->Html->image('logo.png'));

Comment: this will generate error like " Call to a member function image() on a non-object in AppController"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the image path in "configure::write" and access it in view Like:
**Configure::write('CompanyLogo', $this->webroot."img/logo.png");**
and in view you can use this:
**< img src="< ?php echo Configure::read('CompanyLogo');?>"/>**

But good practice using this in view:
**$this->Html->image('logo.png');**